# Enriching a data.table with derived values from another data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

Assume the following data.tables;

```
> valid_event_rows
                TTimeStamp DeviceIDI             TimeOff AlarmGroup Alarmcode LogType idKey MailSend DownTime
    1: 2011-09-15 11:46:39         4 2011-09-15 14:04:16          1      1111       0   791        1 138 mins
    2: 2011-09-15 11:47:14         4 2011-09-15 14:04:15          1      1015       2   793        0 137 mins
    3: 2011-09-15 11:47:37         4 2011-09-15 14:04:18          1      1001       2   794        0 137 mins
    4: 2011-09-15 11:57:34         4 2011-09-15 13:57:42          1      7111       2   795        0 120 mins
    5: 2011-09-15 14:58:43         4 2011-09-15 17:59:03          1      7111       2   795        0 181 mins
    ...


> observed_failures
          Group  AlarmCode                    Description  ErrorType
  1:     System        916        HW-profile not selected          1
  2:     System       1001                    Manual stop          1
  3:     System       1003     Emergency switch activated          1
  4:     System       1004                  External stop          0
  5:     System       1005        Availability - low wind          W
  ...
```

I am aiming to extend the `observed_failures` table with a new column `Frequency` which contains the `count()` for the respective `Alarmcode` in the `valid_event_rows` table.

---

I have unsuccessfully attempted to do it by parsing the first table and counting all occurrences into a new DT `failures_distribution`and then binding the `Frequency` column into the desired table.

```
# Generate a High Level view root cause of observed failures
observed_failures <- event_categories[Number %in% event_data$Alarmcode]
observed_failures <- observed_failures[order(Number, decreasing = FALSE)]

# Build a DF with AlarmCode | Frequency
failures_distribution <- (count(sort(valid_event_rows$Alarmcode)))

# Bind the Frequency column to the table
failures_summary <- cbind(observed_failures,failures_distribution$freq)        # BUG (!!!) 
colnames(failures_summary)[5] <- "Frequency"
```

However this did not work because some events on `event_categories` are (by design) duplicated and therefore screws up the cbind value to frequency mapping.

I could fix it by sorting and removing the duplicates in the `event_categories` but I would rather learn what is the most appropriate way of doing it inline.

Please bear in mind that I am new to R.

Comment: If you can `dput` the data I should be able to do this for you

Comment: Instead of a `cbind` try doing a `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give `dplyr` a try, `count` the alarmcodes in valid_event_rows, then `left_join` those frequencies to the observed_failures:

```
library(dplyr)
frequencies <- count(valid_event_rows, AlarmCode)
failures_summary <- left_join(observed_failures, frequencies, on = 'AlarmCode')
```

To explain the magic: `count` counts the rows in the data.frame, grouped by AlarmCode. The output is a new data.frame with two variables: 'AlarmCode' and 'n'. `left_join` then joins the data.frames using the variable specified with on, by using left_join all observations in observed_failures are kept, and the corresponding frequencies (if any) are bound to it.

Comment: I keep seeing references to dplyr almost everywhere. Gotta learn it I guess! Thanks again!